# How to connect to WiFi without reboot?

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, pi-zero-w

I just put a freshly flashed card (with 2017-09-07-raspbian-stretch-lite) into a Raspberry Pi Zero W.

Then I added these lines:

```
network={
    ssid="myWifiSsid"
    psk="myWifiPassword"
}
```

to `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`.

The data entered was 100% correct. I waited 10 minutes and checked: It did not connect automatically.

Then I went back to the [official instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md) and ran `sudo wpa_cli reconfigure` as suggested. Same result: It did not connect.

Then I tried to manually restart wlan0:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Still the same: Is does not connect.

Then I did a reboot and it instantly automatically connected.

It's soo frustrating. It feels like the official instructions aren't tested at all.

So what is missing here, how can this be done without a reboot?

Comment: I have also noticed this. Very frustrating!

Answer (score 39):

As of 2018, the previous answers don't work anymore, you need to run the following command:

```
sudo wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure
```

Source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=198274#p1238023

Comment: work like magic on Pi4 ! Thanks!

Comment: works perfectly on Pi3 with wifi-to-wifi-bridge (on Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster))

Comment: works also for Pi0w (buster)!

Answer (score 33):

I too saw this issue with my [RaspberryPi Zero W](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-zero-w/) using `2017-09-07-raspbian-stretch-lite`.

Updating the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file, `sudo wpa_cli reconfigure`, and `sudo systemctl restart wpa_supplicant` did not work. My Pi would not get an IP on `wlan0`.

I noticed that `wpa_supplicant` is spawned as a child of the `dhcpcd` service.

```
$ sudo systemctl status

└─dhcpcd.service
  ├─890 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0
  └─912 /sbin/dhcpcd -q -w
```

I found that using [daemon-reload](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/364787/87765) and restarting the `dhcpcd.service` unit worked for me.

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd
```

It [seems like](https://serverfault.com/a/700956/373603) you should first run `sudo systemcl daemon-reload` before restarting `dhcpcd`. I am not entirely sure why, but it seems that the `daemon-reload` will alert service units to config file changes.

If I restarted `dhcpcd` without running `daemon-reload`, I got this warning. `Warning: dhcpcd.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.`, but it restarted just fine with or without `daemon-reload`. So I do not think it's vital, but probably a good practice.

Comment: This works and is the correct solution. But, for anyone who wants to do dual mode wifi (i.e. Raspberry pi hosting a hotspot as well as acting as a base station) please note that this will not work. If you are setting up dual mode wifi, follow this guide here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge.

Assuming that you have done the configuration as per this guide, and want to get things running without reboot; just run sudo systemctl restart wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service followed by sudo systemctl daemon-reload

Comment: daemon-reload may not be needed, as no systemd unit files were modified. If someone tries this procedure without a daemon reload please post your results

Comment: It doesn't work for me on  RaspberryPi Zero W (buster)

Comment: `systemctl restart wpa_supplicant.service` and `systemctl restart dhcpcd.service` did the trick for me on *Buster*

Comment: this worked

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
`sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd`

Answer (score 6):

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3 with `2018-03-13-raspbian-stretch` and my issue is marginally different, but I found a solution, so I think this can help you too.

I boot the RPi with `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` set up so that I have one SSID and password set and the RPi connects automatically to the configured SSID on boot. In addition, I wanted to **change** `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` using some automated text processing script and then **reload the wifi settings**.

After searching around for a bit, I found [this post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=160620) on the official Raspberry Pi forums and found this set of commands inside that worked for me at least:

```
sudo dhclient -r wlan0
sudo ifdown wlan0
sudo ifup wlan0
sudo dhclient -v wlan0
```

I don't know how or why they work, so no guarantees...

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me, also on Pi3 with raspian stretch - thanks!

Comment: this worked for me too, except that I had to use sudo ifconfig wlan0 up/down instead of ifdown wlan0, because that gave some errors

Answer (score 5):

After adding a network in wpa_supplicant.conf:

Run the cli 
(3 commands are used here:  interface, reconfigure and quit)

```
root@raspberrypi:~# wpa_cli
wpa_cli v2.4
Copyright (c) 2004-2015, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors

This software may be distributed under the terms of the BSD license.
See README for more details.


Selected interface 'p2p-dev-wlan0'

Interactive mode

<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
> interface wlan0
Connected to interface 'wlan0.
> reconfigure
OK
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
<3>CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-RESULTS
<3>WPS-AP-AVAILABLE
<3>Trying to associate with XX:Xa:aX:Xa:XX:Xa (SSID='wifissid' freq=2437 MHz)
<3>Associated with XX:Xa:aX:Xa:XX:Xa
<3>WPA: Key negotiation completed with XX:Xa:aX:Xa:XX:Xa [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
<3>CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to XX:Xa:aX:Xa:XX:Xa completed [id=0 id_str=]
> quit
```

Then verify that you have an IP address.

```
root@raspberrypi:~# ifconfig wlan0
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.10.XX.XXX  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.10.XX.XXX
        inet6 fe80::aab2:d96e:d3ef:836d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether bX:XX:Xb:XX:Xe:aX  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 162  bytes 31128 (30.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 75  bytes 11385 (11.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: this got it for me. tyvm

Answer (score 1):

You should run this command line to restart the network

> /etc/init.d/networking restart

Comment: Not in stretch!

Comment: Ideally not in jessie either, since it is also systemd (not SysV) based; that command is anachronistic and at best supported for backward compatibility.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. You must reconfigure wpa supplicant and restart dhcpcd

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster). I made changes in wpa_supplicant.conf and run

```
# wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure
```

But it did not work all the way.

```
# dhclient -v
```

made it work.

I found info at https://kb.isc.org/docs/isc-dhcp-44-manual-pages-dhclient

Output from

```
$ sudo dhclient -v
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/wlan0/a0:f3:c1:26:04:9c
Sending on   LPF/wlan0/a0:f3:c1:26:04:9c
Listening on LPF/eth0/b8:27:eb:1f:ab:6e
Sending on   LPF/eth0/b8:27:eb:1f:ab:6e
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.7.28 on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
DHCPACK of 192.168.7.28 from 192.168.7.1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
bound to 192.168.7.28 -- renewal in 1717 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NetworkManager tool, which uses `nmcli` commands to setup a connection profile.

Install it using apt:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager
```

Comment out `wlan` and `Ethernet` interfaces in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Reboot the device.

Then use:

```
sudo nmcli device wifi con "SSID" password "PSK"
```

to connect to a Wi-Fi network.

Comment: Please don't advise to mix up another networking tool with the already three existing ones (dhcpcd, Debian networking ifupdown, systemd-networkd). Network manager isn't supported by Raspbian so you have to configure it all by hand. First it conflicts with `dhcpcd` and `ifupdown`. You do not respect it in your answer. Then in Raspbian Stretch there are no entries in `/etc/network/interfaces` so there is nothing to comment out.

Comment: Yeah you are right buddy, they conflict with network with other dhcpcd and ifupdown. But NetworkManager seems to be the only way to do this, after following above advices. Raspberry pi's raspbian lite versions have not other option than nmcli.
I haven't tried it on Stretch but, during the installation Network manager itself will give the warning of conflict. If you have a solution I'm always ready to learn that method.

Comment: Just with `sudo systemctl stop wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service` and `sudo systemctl start wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service` you can stop and start a WiFi connection just as you like. How to do it you can look at [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/88234/79866) or [Access point as WiFi repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866) or [Switch between wifi client and access point without reboot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93312/79866) or other similar solutions.

Comment: A very valid point by @Ingo. Just to add - if you are using Node.js, and want to do things using npm packages, check the documentation thoroughly. Most of the npm packages use nmcli in the background which does not work on Raspberry pi. It is not even installed. So, please proceed with caution.

Comment: It's indeed possible to use `network-manager` (or `wicd` or any other networking tool for that matter) on Raspbian. It would be useful however if you described how to set them up.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 1:

I landed up on this answer with my Raspberry pi Zero W configured as a dual mode wifi and I wanted to change the wifi credentials (wifi router that `wlan0` must connect to) by sharing them over the ap0 interface (which had a REST API hosted on it) with a mobile app.

The thing is I assumed that the accepted answer or any other answers will work in my case. But that was not the case.

So, for anyone who has landed here just like me, please follow the setup steps mentioned [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge).

Then, for a change in wifi connection without reboot, I am currently testing with 2 ways:

1. `wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure`
2. `sudo systemctl restart wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service`

Once the tests are done, I will be updating it here.

Comment: I am currently in the process of testing things. Will keep this updated.

Comment: i'm in the same situation (dhcpcd has started wpa_supplicant via hook)... whatever i try i always end up with "Association requets to driver failed" or "failed to enable fw supplicant" with "wap_cli" after restarting dhcpcd "wpa_cli" works but the AP is inaccessible. I teste new and old wifi firmware so i assume wpa_supplicant is somehow broken (and not it only runs one wpa service).

Comment: Ok i switched the solution [systemd] (https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-router-repeater-optional-with-bridge) solution. Only calling `wap_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure` works. But sometimes the AP hangs after changing `wlan0`. But so far it is the best solution on `2021-01-11-raspios-buster-armhf-lite`

Comment: The hangs of AP were unbearable. I think AP+Client via hostap and `/sbin/iw dev wlan0 interface add ap@wlan0 type __ap` is simply not working. I hope someone can prove me wrong. I ended up using a cheap 2€ wifi dongle systemd-networkd + 2x wpa_supplicant -> wlan0 (client) and wlan1 (AP). That makes also `wpa_cli ... reconfigure` work like a charm