# Connecting RPI Zero W2 to different Wi-Fi AP simultaneously or sequentially

Tags: networking, wifi, raspberry-pi-os, pi-zero-w-2

I am trying to use a RPI Zero W2 to solve a problem I have with collecting files from an IoT device. Specifically, I don't know how to setup the Wi-Fi network(s). Any inputs to my questions would be appreciated.

**Existing Setup:**

1. IoT device acting as a web server and hosting a Wi-Fi access point (say 10.10.x.x subnet).
2. Wi-Fi access point providing internet access (say 192.168.x.x subnet).

**My Requirement / Need a RPI Zero W2 to do the below:**

1. Connect to the IoT device (1) and download some log files using a REST API. (could be a few GB)
2. Connect to the Wi-Fi access point (2) and upload the log files to some cloud storage.

Note 1: I don’t need to provide internet access to the IoT device. It is acting as a web server only and does not generate outgoing traffic.

Note 2: I can take care of the code to do the download and upload mentioned in point 1. & 2. Need guidance on how to setup the networks at this point.

**Questions:**

1. How do I connect to two Wi-Fi access points simultaneously? I was planning to add a second Wi-Fi NIC using a USB dongle & OTG cable. Alternatively can these connections be made simultaneously on the single built-in Wi-Fi NIC?
2. Would it be better to alternate connecting to the two access points? For example connect to the IoT device Wi-Fi AP, download files, disconnect from that AP, connect to the internet Wi-Fi AP, upload to internet, disconnect from the internet Wi-Fi AP, and then repeat.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting questions.

###### N.B.: I can't replicate your network setup. Consequently, the following answers have not been fully verified. I feel the `alternate/sequential connections` approach will work for you assuming both APs (IoT & WiFi) are on functional networks.

### Summary:

A "simultaneous" solution is possible only with hardware & drivers that support it. AFAIK, there is no RPi hardware that does.

An "alternate/sequential" solution is possible, and illustrated below. This solution employs the `wpa_cli` app (part of `wpa_supplicant`) to rotate AP priorities using `set network <id> priority <n>` followed by a `reassociate` to switch to the higher priority network id/AP. This rather obtuse approach is necessary to avoid the `select_network` option that disables the other networks.

#### WRT Q1: connect to 2 Wi-Fi access points simultaneously ?

[As I understand it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/470484/286615), this requires both an interface (hardware) and a driver that supports dual-channel management. You should run the `iw list` command on your Pi 0 W2 to determine if your system currently supports "simultaneous".

For my RPi (a 3B+ running bullseye), I get the result below where `<=1` effectively means that the "simultaneous" option is not available for my 3B+. If you get `<=1` result, then "simultaneous" is likely not available for you either. This may guide your selection of a suitable USB NIC if you want "simultaneous".

```
$ iw list | grep -A 4 'valid interface combinations'
    valid interface combinations:
         * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
           total <= 3, #channels <= 2
         * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1, #{ P2P-client } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
           total <= 4, #channels <= 1
```

#### WRT Q2: `alternate/sequential wifi connections`

I believe this will do what you need using the single `wlan0` interface built into your Pi 0 2W. You may wish to do some reading (see **REFERENCES** below) before you begin, and get some background on this process. Based on my reading of this & [other research](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linux+wpa_supplicant+switch+between+wifi+networks), and under the assumptions stated above, this option will work. The procedure is outlined below in two steps:

1. Declare both networks in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`
   You didn't show your `wpa_supplicant.conf` file, so I've created this one to serve as an example:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

country=GB

network={
   ssid="MyWiFiAP"
   psk="mypasswd"
}

network={
   ssid="MyIoTAP"
   psk="mypasswd2"
}
```

2. We use `wpa_cli` in its *interactive mode* below, but all of these commands may be written as *stand-alone* commands, suitable for scripting:

```bsh
$ wpa_cli 

#  ... # preliminaries...

> list_networks
network id / ssid / bssid / flags
0    MyWiFiAP    any [CURRENT]
1    MyIoTAP     any 
# The above result shows the two SSIDs configured in wpa_supplicant.conf  

> get_network 1 priority
0
> get_network 0 priority
0
# The above results show the *priority* of the two SSID/network ids (0 & 1)  

> set_network 1 priority 2
OK 
# Assign a higher priority to network id 1 (MyIoTAP) 

> reassociate
OK  
... a series of CTRL_EVENTS are listed ...
# Connect to the higher priority network (MyIoTAP) 

> list_networks
network id / ssid / bssid / flags
0    MyWiFiAP    any
1    MyIoTAP     any [CURRENT] 
# after `reassociate`, connection has moved to higher priority network/SSID  

# to restore the original connection to MyWiFiAP: 
# use the `set_network` priority commands above, 
# follow that with another `reassociate`
# Note: when priorities of all networks are equal, 
# wpa_supplicant defaults to the one with the strongest signal  

> quit
# terminates the wpa_cli interactive session  

$
```

And that's it... the `alternate/sequential wifi connections` process. You should verify this works with your network configuration *manually* as I've shown above. Once verified, you may use the equivalent *stand-alone* commands to automate the process in a script - or experiment with [`wpa_cli` running in *daemon* mode](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wpa_supplicant#wpa_cli_action_script).

---

##### REFERENCES:

1. RE: [`wlan0` vs. `p2p-dev-wlan0`](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=224576#p1377173)
2. [ArchWiki `wpa_supplicant` documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wpa_supplicant#Connecting_with_wpa_cli)
3. `man wpa_cli` on your RPi
4. [Linux Find Wireless WiFi Driver Chipset Information](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-find-wireless-driver-chipset/)

Comment: unfortunately my RPI zero w2 returns <=1. so will have to go with the alternating connections to each wifi AP.

Comment: @Sachin: `"my RPI zero w2 returns <=1"` - not surprising considering RPi priority is on ***low cost***. On the bright side, administration of such a beast might be x-painful? I just skimmed through this [recent, interesting post on Vivek Gite's Linux blog](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-find-wireless-driver-chipset/); if dual simultaneous is what you want, there *may* be some information there to help you find it. But in any case, please do let us know how this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am now able to switch between Wi-Fi networks with the following commands:

```
wpa_cli -i wlan0 set_network 0 priority 2
wpa_cli -i wlan0 set_network 1 priority 0
wpa_cli -i wlan0 reassociate
```

and able to switch back to the first Wi-Fi with:

```
wpa_cli -i wlan0 set_network 0 priority 0
wpa_cli -i wlan0 set_network 1 priority 2
wpa_cli -i wlan0 reassociate
```

If I didn't use the -i switch it would default to p2p-dev-wlan0 instead of wlan0.

Reference: [Switching to a different wireless network when it is available](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/81941/switching-to-a-different-wireless-network-when-it-is-available/136971#136971)

Comment: Add the following on its own line (I put it at the top so its easy to find again) to disable the p2p-dev-wlan0 interface: `p2p_disabled=1` in the file `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. I rebooted, but a daemon-reload or some such may also work. With the p2p interface disabled, wpa_cli defaults to the wlan0 interface.