# Connect to WiFi with CLI without rebooting

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant

I want to connect my Raspberry Pi 4B to my Wifi network via CLI (technically, by node.js/python scripts) without rebooting it.

For the moment I am modifying the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file by adding my Wifi info:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=JP

network={
        ssid="*SSID*"
        psk="*pass*"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Then, I found I should run the command `sudo wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure` to run the wifi with the new data, but unfortunately, it doesn't work. I got the message `OK`, but when I check `ifconfig`, I have no IP on wlan0.

I tried also to do

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

without success. And then I tried

```
sudo killall wpa_supplicant
sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -D wext -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -B
```

And again, it failed, giving me the following error message:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
```

What would be the give why to apply the new `wpa_supplicant.conf` file, or if there is another way to connect the RPi to Wifi without GUI and reboot.

PS: I am running the following Raspian 10 (buster)
PPS: I followed the solutions of [that post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/73749/how-to-connect-to-wifi-without-reboot), but no one could work.

EDIT: the result of the  command `systemctl status dhcpcd`

```
* dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-09-13 15:00:46 JST; 2h 16min ago
  Process: 397 ExecStart=/usr/lib/dhcpcd5/dhcpcd -q -b (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 457 (dhcpcd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
           `-457 /sbin/dhcpcd -q -b

Sep 13 16:10:26 raspberrypi dhcpcd[457]: eth0: carrier lost
Sep 13 16:10:26 raspberrypi dhcpcd[457]: eth0: deleting address fe80::c62c:bf9d:e38d:ee8f
Sep 13 16:10:26 raspberrypi dhcpcd[457]: eth0: deleting route to 192.168.4.0/24
Sep 13 17:17:33 raspberrypi dhcpcd[457]: eth0: carrier acquired
Sep 13 17:17:33 raspberrypi dhcpcd[457]: eth0: IAID 01:4c:5c:00
Sep 13 17:17:33 raspberrypi dhcpcd[457]: eth0: adding address fe80::c62c:bf9d:e38d:ee8f
Sep 13 17:17:33 raspberrypi dhcpcd[457]: eth0: probing address 192.168.4.1/24
Sep 13 17:17:34 raspberrypi dhcpcd[457]: eth0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Sep 13 17:17:38 raspberrypi dhcpcd[457]: eth0: using static address 192.168.4.1/24
Sep 13 17:17:38 raspberrypi dhcpcd[457]: eth0: adding route to 192.168.4.0/24
```

EDIT 2 :
I also added a static IP on eth0 by editing the file `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.4.1/24
```

Comment: For example in the post, I shared in the PPS. It said it's the recommended method from 2018, so I assumed it was still true (and when I look on Google that command often came out). For dhcpcd I' don't know. I'm not really knowledgeable about networking.

Comment: I'm connected in LAN directly with my PC for testing. But in the final version of my project, I'll be connected in Bluetooth (so no network connection) and I will send the Wifi info to connect the Rpi (that's already done). I just need to set up the wifi.

Comment: I edited the post with the result of the command. Sorry, but because I don't know that much about networking, I don't know what could be useful.
I used the previous command because it popped to me several times on different topics and pages. So I gave it a try

Answer (score 1):

You have something different in the configuration files which prevents `dhcpcd` from starting `wpa_supplicant`. This is how the service status looks on my system:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status dhcpcd
● dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-09-24 13:30:39 CEST; 2 weeks 4 days ago
 Main PID: 442 (dhcpcd)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
           ├─  442 /sbin/dhcpcd -q -b
           └─21837 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dnl80211,wext
```

Note your log doesn't have the last line that mine has.

You could try using `raspi-config` to configure your WiFi, then `systemctl restart dhcpcd` if you want to avoid the reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Default networking on *Raspberry Pi OS* uses `dhcpcd` which starts `wpa_supplicant` with a hook, it is unclear what attempting to run wpa_supplicant would actually do.

You are connected by Ethernet to something, but not wireless.
`using static address 192.168.4.1/24` fills me with trepidation (particularly by someone who states "I don't know that much about networking"), but you have OBVIOUSLY changed something.

Normally you would restart networking with `sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd` but if you are attempting to connect to a different network which may have different settings who knows what will happen.

You should try and repeat `systemctl status dhcpcd`.

Comment: Yeah, I changed a while ago the ethernet configuration to have static IP on it. But I forgot about it, sorry.
Actually, the Pi is connected by LAN top another RPi (with WLAN deactivated). The RPi I'm trying to connect should share the internet via LAN connection on static IP on eth0. I only modified the eth0, but I forgot how exactly I did. I do not know how much eth0 and wlan0 can interfere?

Comment: And for testing, now, I replaced the second Pi with my PC, in order to use SSH

Comment: I edited the original post with my edit on the dhcpcd.conf

Comment: I tried the command `sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd` but it didn't work :/
Also, the Raspberry pi website also said to use the command `wpa_cli -i wlan0 reconfigure`: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/computers/configuration.html#using-the-command-line

Comment: @DarkPatate Posting a link to a page which has ABSOLUTELY nothing to do with your assertion is futile, as is any attempt to help. There is no such claim.